# Optimize various brightness image for OCR using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have following types of images:

[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]
[image: Example3]
[image: Example4]
[image: Example5]
[image: Example6]
[image: Example7]
[image: Example8]
[image: Example9]

I would like to preprocess them to do best OCR result, but as you can see they are in different brightness and different sharpness ... is possible to do some "generic" adjustments to extract text for OCR with the best result?

Comment: Relevant: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325368992_Rolling_bilateral_filter-based_text_image_deblurring

Comment: For adjustments to sharpness, I'm not aware of an automatic solution. But for brightness, you should look at offerings for [adaptive thresholding and Otsu binarization](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **easy ocr** is giving proper result for these cases. This will work for blurred and unblurred cases.

```
import easyocr
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance


def unsharp_mask(image, kernel_size=(5, 5), sigma=1.0, amount=1.0, threshold=0):
    """Return a sharpened version of the image, using an unsharp mask."""
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, kernel_size, sigma)
    sharpened = float(amount + 1) * image - float(amount) * blurred
    sharpened = np.maximum(sharpened, np.zeros(sharpened.shape))
    sharpened = np.minimum(sharpened, 255 * np.ones(sharpened.shape))
    sharpened = sharpened.round().astype(np.uint8)
    if threshold > 0:
        low_contrast_mask = np.absolute(image - blurred) < threshold
        np.copyto(sharpened, image, where=low_contrast_mask)
    return sharpened

def increase_brightness(img, value):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

    lim = 255 - value
    v[v > lim] = 255
    v[v <= lim] += value

    final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return img

image = cv2.imread('if8nC.png')
sharpened = unsharp_mask(image)
imag = increase_brightness(sharpened, value=10) # 60 ->5qoOk.png #10 -> if8nC.png
cv2.imwrite('resize.png',imag)

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext('resize.png')
for detection in result:
        print(detection)
```

The only adjustment u have to make is change in brightness value from 0 to 100. It worked for all cases.
The output is

```
([[1, 0], [282, 0], [282, 68], [1, 68]], 'Tvrdosin', 0.4517089309490733)
```

Comment: Did `easyOCR` work for the attached samples?

Comment: It failed for 2 blurred case such as instead of 's' it detect as 't'.. May be image sharpening with threshold input will help for those case.

Comment: Please edit the answer to include your findings. Finally by suggest ways to improve sharpening

Comment: I had edited the code with image sharpening. You can play around brightness value for exceptional cases.

Comment: This answer would be better if you add some of the results. Great answer BTW +1